# Is their a better way to populate ignored column from another table using room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have two related tables `item` and `purchase`. The `purchase` class contains an `ignored` column `itemName` which I want to fill with `itemName from item`

> Although I have a method but I am concerned if there is `a better way`
> `to achieve it` because `my way has to do with reading all items from the database` then comparing `purchase.itemOwnerID` to `item.itemID`

> Here is my populating code along with others

```
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    sharedViewModel.requestAllPurchases()
    sharedViewModel.requestAllItems() //requesting all items 
}

val allPurchases by sharedViewModel.allPurchases.collectAsState()
val allItems by sharedViewModel.allItems.collectAsState() //getting all items requested



if (allPurchases is RequestState.Success && allItems is RequestState.Success) {
    (allPurchases as RequestState.Success<List<Purchase>>).data.forEach { purchase ->
        (allItems as RequestState.Success<List<Item>>).data.first { it.itemID == purchase.itemOwnerID }//comparism
            .apply {
                purchase.itemName = itemName
                purchase.costPrice = salePrice
            }
    }
}
```

> Model

```
@Entity(tableName = "items", indices = [Index(value = ["itemName"], unique = true)])
    data class Item(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var itemID: Int,
        var categoryOwnerID: Int = 0,
        var itemName: String,
        var costPrice: Int,
        var salePrice: Int,
    ) {
        @Ignore
        var desiredQuantity: Int = 0
    }

@Entity(tableName = "purchases")
data class Purchase(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var purchaseID: Int,
    var itemOwnerID: Int,
    var quantity: Int,
    var soldPrice: Int,
) {
    @Ignore
    var itemName: String = ""
}

sealed class RequestState<out T> {
object Idle : RequestState<Nothing>()
object Loading : RequestState<Nothing>()
data class Success<T>(val data: T) : RequestState<T>()
data class Error(val error: Throwable) : RequestState<Nothing>()
```

}

> @Dao

```
@Query("select * from items order by itemName asc")
fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

@Query("select * from purchases order by purchaseID asc")
fun getAllPurchases(): Flow<List<Purchase>>
```

> Repository

```
val getAllItems: Flow<List<Item>> = itemDao.getAllItems()
val getAllPurchases: Flow<List<Purchase>> = itemDao.getAllPurchases()
```

> SharedViewModel

```
 private var _allItems = MutableStateFlow<RequestState<List<Item>>>(RequestState.Idle)
    val allItems: StateFlow<RequestState<List<Item>>> = _allItems

    fun requestAllItems() {
        _allItems.value = RequestState.Loading
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.getAllItems.collect {
                    _allItems.value = RequestState.Success(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _allItems.value = RequestState.Error(e)
        }

    }

private var _allPurchases =
        MutableStateFlow<RequestState<List<Purchase>>>(RequestState.Idle)
    val allPurchases: StateFlow<RequestState<List<Purchase>>> = _allPurchases

    fun requestAllPurchases() {
        _allPurchases.value = RequestState.Loading
        try {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                repository.getAllPurchases.collect {
                    _allPurchases.value = RequestState.Success(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _allPurchases.value = RequestState.Error(e)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use join query here?

Comment: Okay. Let me search about it online

Comment: @AnkitaPatel , it works like charm.

I am just glad I asked the question.

Comment: @AnkitaPatel can you include it with a link as an answer so I could upvote and mark it if you won't mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create another data class based on the columns needed, then use a `@Query` to get the needed columns from the database or a join query for multiple tables like the one below

```
Query("SELECT P.purchaseID, P.itemOwnerID, P.quantity, P.soldPrice, I.itemName FROM purchases as P INNER JOIN items AS I ON I.itemID = P.itemOwnerID")
fun getAllPurchases(): Flow<List<Purchase>>
```

More info could be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#return-subset)